# Difference between LibSVM and LibSVM in scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

I run grid search with LibSVM (grid.py) and LibSVM in scikit-learn but received different results on the sample file "heart_scale"

My scikit-learn code

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

data = load_svmlight_file("heart_scale")
(X, y) = (data[0].toarray(), data[1])

# Using the same ranges for C and gamma as default in LibSVM grid.py
gamma_range = np.logspace(3, -15, 10, base=2)
C_range = np.logspace(-5, 15, 11, base=2)

tuned_parameters = [{'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': gamma_range ,
                         'C': C_range}]
grid = GridSearchCV(SVC(), tuned_parameters, cv=5)
grid.fit(X, y)

print("Best parameters set found on development set:")
print(grid.best_params_)
print("The best parameters are %s with a score of %0.2f"
          % (grid.best_params_, grid.best_score_))
```

Output

```
Best parameters set found on development set:
{'kernel': 'rbf', 'C': 2.0, 'gamma': 0.0078125}
The best parameters are {'kernel': 'rbf', 'C': 2.0, 'gamma': 0.0078125} with a score of 0.84
```

LibSVM

```
python grid.py heart_scale
```

Output

```
2048.0 0.0001220703125 84.4444
```

Could anyone tell me how to achieve the same results as LibSVM with LibSVM in scikit-learn?

Comment: I expect the difference comes down to each of the CV folds being different between the two. You could probably see this by rerunning one of your scripts a few times. If there are ways to specify and pass your own folds, then you could do that. If not, you could write up your own grid search where you can specify the same folds in both

Comment: And there is also this: ```The underlying LinearSVC implementation uses a random number generator to select features when fitting the model. It is thus not uncommon, to have slightly different results for the same input data. If that happens, try with a smaller tol parameter.``` [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#tips-on-practical-use)